# Rotation Matrix from Covariance of 3D point-cloud

Tags: covariance, eigenvalues, svd, rotation

I am trying to retreive rotation matrix from a rotated 3D point cloud covariance matrix, using SVD decomposition (as done in [SimNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.16118) and [MVTrans](https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.11683)). Here how I computed the covariance matrix from 3D point cloud (CAD model of the rotated object):

```
def cov_mat(self, rot, pos):
"""Returns the 3x3 covariance matrix of the point cloud in camera coordinates"""
point_cloud = self.raw / 1000.0
points_cam = np.dot(point_cloud, rot.T) 
centered_points_cam = points_cam  - np.mean(points_cam, axis=0)
cov = np.cov(centered_points_cam, rowvar=False)
return cov
```

Here code function to retrieve rotation from covariance:

```
def _solve_for_rotation_from_cov_matrix(self, cov_matrix):
assert cov_matrix.shape[0] == 3
assert cov_matrix.shape[1] == 3
U, D, Vh = np.linalg.svd(cov_matrix, full_matrices=True)
d = (np.linalg.det(U) * np.linalg.det(Vh)) < 0.0
if d:
    D[-1] = -D[-1]
    U[:, -1] = -U[:, -1]
# Rotation from world to points.
rotation = np.eye(4)
rotation[0:3, 0:3] = U
return rotation
```

Using this implementation, I do not get the correct (ground truth ) true rotation matrix, can you expolain me the reason ?